# How to controll vessel without crew?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I am building a cart to throw it to Eve, where there are some astronauts waiting for it, but every time I click on "launch" it says "This vessel has no remote-controlled or manned modules. It won't be controllable".

What should I do to send the cart to Eve with no crew on it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to include a crew-less satellite part from the 'Pods' tab that is not the Command Seat. Right-clicking on them for more info will show "Unmanned" under the **Command** heading. Do note that if a satellite pod loses all power, the vessel will become effectively dead in space, and you cannot even throttle liquid engines on to generate power, so having a couple solar panels deployed once in space is a good idea.

If you are playing in career mode, the first satellite pod is unlocked by *Flight Control* for 30 science.